# How to add color interpretation for raster bands using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

I have 3 separate 1-band GeoTIFF files. The color interpretation for band is gray. I want a 3-band RGB file. I've used gdal_merge.py

```
gdal_merge.py -separate file1.tif file2.tif file3.tif -o output_file.tif
```

But the color interpretation for the 3 bands of the resulting output_file.tif is gray, undefined, undefined. Apart from that, **all pixels are 0**.

If I execute pct2rgb.py, I get a RGB file:

```
pct2rgb.py output_file.tif output_file_rgb.tif
```

But of course, the pixels are 0 too. So, I have 3 questions:

- Is gdal_merge.py the right tool to combine 3 1-band files in one 3-band RGB file?
- Why am I getting undefined color interpretation for bands?
- Is pct2rgb the right tool to transform 3-band files with this color interpretation to RGB files?

**UPDATE**: The rasters does not have a color table. Just color interpretation: Gray.

On other hand, pixel values goes from 0 to 1023 (this is deliberate)

More data: they're rotated rasters (no north up), but all of them have the same geotransform.

**UPDATE 2**: I can warp the images to make them north up, construct a VRT and add ColorInterp for each band, but I still get color interpretation as gray, undefined, undefined in the output result.

The problem is I need to create a color table in, at least, the first band. I know [the way to create them](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster#Howtocreateormodifyanimagecolortable), but I don't know how many entries should my table have. Why are there 13 entries in the example of GDAL Raster FAQ? All the pixels have values between 0 and 1023, if helps.

**UPDATE 3**: Apparently, [there's no way in the TIFF format to really specify the color interpretation of each band. The way GDAL builds the color interpretation when reading a TIFF file is a combination of the value of the PHOTOMETRIC and EXTRASAMPLES tag](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-April/028451.html).

Reading about these tags:

- [PHOTOMETRIC](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/photometricinterpretation.html) represents the color space of the image data. A value of 2 means that the components of a pixel value are RGB, but it assumes Byte pixels, and I have UInt16 pixels (I tried `-co "PHOTOMETRIC=rgb"`, and got an error). So, I can't specify PHOTOMETRIC tag for the output file.
- [EXTRASAMPLES](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/extrasamples.html) specifies that each pixel has N extra components. I'm not sure about how to use this tag to create my merged file. Or if a I need it.

So, in update 2 I suggest the creation of a ColorTable, but how? In my 3 input files, pixel values go from 0 to 1023. Do I have to match them with colors? Do I have to create a ColorTable with 1024 inputs? How?

In update 3, seems that I could use some GeoTIFF tags when creating the merged file, but I'm not sure if I really can use them, or how.

Comment: Try this: Use gdal_merge as you did, then gdal_translate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB, for whatever reason gdal_merge doesn't honor the -co.  This *appeared* to work for me.  Although I may be misunderstanding your target.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I want to merge 3 single band geotiffs in one 3-band geotiff. My problem is the output of gdal_merge is actually empty (pixels = 0). I can't use that output for anything.

Comment: Is it possible to post the data somewhere, something seems amiss.

Comment: I've asked my boss, and I can't publish data :-(. I actually could mix the files with a standalone code, that copies band by band the input files in the output. I'd like to do it with gdal_merge. My poblem is I can't set RGB color interpretation for the output file with gdal_merge.

Comment: Maybe, I had a similar problem. Got this working with rgb2pct.py. Why?, I dunno. Description of command: This utility will compute an optimal pseudo-color table for a given RGB image using a median cut algorithm on a downsampled RGB histogram. Then I run gdal_translate with expand rgb.

Answer (score 6):

gdal_merge.py is the correct tool to 'stack' your input images.

Assuming that your first band has a valid color table you could use:

`gdal_merge.py -separate -pct -o output_file.tif file1.tif file2.tif file3.tif`

Note: The command has been reformatted with `-o output_file.tif` before the list of inputs.

From the docs:

> -pct:
>   Grab a pseudocolor table from the first input image, and use it for the output. Merging pseudocolored images this way assumes that all input files use the same color table.

I would test your output with `gdalinfo -stats` to make sure it is being stacked properly.

**Updated for OP**

From the [osgeo list](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-April/028451.html), it looks like you might try a different format to check the results:

> There's no way in the TIFF format to really specify the color interpretation of each band. The way GDAL builds the color interpretation when reading a TIFF file is a combination of the value of the PHOTOMETRIC and EXTRASAMPLES tag.

-Evan (the poster) knows GDAL inside and out.

Comment: I actually did that, but I get "ERROR 6: SetColorTable() not supported for multi-sample TIFF files.". And I get 0 for all pixels. I'm not sure about the meaning of this error.

Comment: Ok,updated question. I need a color table for first band.

Comment: Mmm... thanks for the response. I'm trying those options. Seems than I can't use PHOTOMETRIC=rgb because my datatype is not int. But I'm on it...

Answer (score 4):

The first way I can think of is to build a vrt, edit and translate:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate output.vrt file1.tif file2.tif file3.tif
```

add the color interp tag where needed:

```
...
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
<ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
<NoDataValue>255</NoDataValue>
<ComplexSource>
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">test.tif</SourceFilename>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="42" RasterYSize="22" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="42" BlockYSize="22" />
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="42" ySize="22" />
  <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="42" ySize="22" />
  <NODATA>-32768</NODATA>
</ComplexSource>
```

and then:

```
gdal_translate output.vrt output.tif
```

Comment: I tried, but my raster files are rotated...

Comment: Meaning they don't have the same SRS/geotransforms?

Comment: No,they all have the same geotransforms,but they're no north-up rasters (rotation parameters are not 0). And gdalbuildvrt does not support rotated geo transforms. I don't want to warp them.

Comment: Mmmm, ok. If I warp them to create north up rasters, I can build the VRT, and add ColorInterp where needed, buy I still get gray, undefined, undefined. I need to create a color table for first band, but I don't know how. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your input grayscale band has values from 0 to 1024, but RGB only allows values from 0 to 255 for each band.

You can use `gdal_translate -scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]` to rescale your source file.

In a second run, you can stack your three bands with gdal_merge.py and apply `-co "PHOTOMETRIC=rgb"`.

Comment: Yes, fyi in pyqgis you can use the following in GDAL tools to enforce RGBA interpretation: 'EXTRA':'-co \"PHOTOMETRIC=RGB\" -srcalpha -dstalpha'