# Update colour interpretation with gdal apps

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

My problem started when I wanted to build a vrt from a set of tif files: it didn't work because some images were in red,green,blue,undefined colour interpretation while others were in red,green,blue,alpha.

My workaround (based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48034/how-to-add-color-interpretation-for-raster-bands-using-gdal) post) was to copy all images with `gdal_translate -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB -co ALPHA=YES`. But isn't possible to simply edit the colour interpretation (e.g. with gdal_edit.py) in order to avoid creating new files?

Comment: I suppose you could open the tiff with python and set the color interpretation of the fourth band into alpha but I don't know how. Some inspiration may be found from http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SetColorInterpretation-for-a-GeoTiff-using-GDAL-not-working-td5091839.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GDAL trunk version you can change the colorinterpretation with gdal_edit

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_edit.dox

> **-colorinterp_X** red|green|blue|alpha|undefined (GDAL >= 2.3) Change the color interpretation of band X (where X is a valid band number,
>   starting at 1)